# Error when requesting from laravel blade button

Tags: laravel, routes, request, dompdf

Now, I am trying to make a request to get input from dashboard.blade. then received in pdf controller, in the controller will generate pdf report

**PDF CONTROLLER**

```
public function generateShopPdf(Request $request){

    // $name="hello";
    // $pdf->loadView('draft',['name'=>$name]);
    // // // Extract the necessary parameters from the $data array
    $minDate = $request->input('minDate');
    $maxDate = $request->input('maxDate');
    $from_date = $request->input('from_date');
    $to_date = $request->input('to_date');
    $distinctRfmDates = json_decode($request->input('distinctRfmDates'), true);
    $rfGraphData = json_decode($request->input('rfGraphData'), true);
    $rmGraphData = json_decode($request->input('rmGraphData'), true);
    $fmGraphData = json_decode($request->input('fmGraphData'), true);
    $rfmMeanData = json_decode($request->input('rfmMeanData'), true);
    $clusterMeanRfmData = json_decode($request->input('clusterMeanRfmData'), true);
    $shopDetailsData = json_decode($request->input('shopDetailsData'), true);

    $params = [
        'minDate'=>$minDate,
        'maxDate'=>$maxDate,
        'from_date'=>$from_date,
        'to_date'=>$to_date,
        'distinctRfmDates'=>$distinctRfmDates,
        'rfGraphData' => $rfGraphData, 
        'rmGraphData' => $rmGraphData, 
        'fmGraphData' => $fmGraphData,
        'rfmMeanData' => $rfmMeanData,
        'clusterMeanRfmData'=>$clusterMeanRfmData,
        'shopDetailsData'=> $shopDetailsData
    ];

    $pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadView('pdf_shop', $params)->setOptions(['defaultFont' => 'sans-serif']);
    return $pdf->download('shop_details.pdf');
}

public function generateProdPdf(Request $request){

    // $name="hello";
    // $pdf->loadView('draft',['name'=>$name]);
    // // // Extract the necessary parameters from the $data array
    $minDate = $request->input('minDate');
    $maxDate = $request->input('maxDate');
    $from_date = $request->input('from_date');
    $to_date = $request->input('to_date');
    $distinctRfmDates = json_decode($request->input('distinctRfmDates'), true);
    $rfGraphData = json_decode($request->input('rfGraphData'), true);
    $rmGraphData = json_decode($request->input('rmGraphData'), true);
    $fmGraphData = json_decode($request->input('fmGraphData'), true);
    $rfmMeanData = json_decode($request->input('rfmMeanData'), true);
    $clusterMeanRfmData = json_decode($request->input('clusterMeanRfmData'), true);
    $prodDetailsData = json_decode($request->input('prodDetailsData'), true);

    $params = [
        'minDate'=>$minDate,
        'maxDate'=>$maxDate,
        'from_date'=>$from_date,
        'to_date'=>$to_date,
        'distinctRfmDates'=>$distinctRfmDates,
        'rfGraphData' => $rfGraphData, 
        'rmGraphData' => $rmGraphData, 
        'fmGraphData' => $fmGraphData,
        'rfmMeanData' => $rfmMeanData,
        'clusterMeanRfmData'=>$clusterMeanRfmData,
        'prodDetailsData'=> $prodDetailsData
    ];

    $pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadView('pdf_product', $params)->setOptions(['defaultFont' => 'sans-serif']);
    return $pdf->download('product_details.pdf');
}
```

**Dashboard.blade**

```
form action="{{route('route.generate.prodPdf')}}" method="GET" target="_blank"
```

- **web.php**

```
Route::get('/generatePdf/prod', [PdfController::class, 'generateProdPdf'])->name('route.generate.prodPdf');

Route::get('/generatePdf/shop', [PdfController::class,'generateShopPdf'])->name('route.generate.shopPdf');`
```

please help me out on calling the `generateProdPdf` function

ERROR: The site cannot be reached.
Already cache route and Serve

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: the site cannot be reach, already cache route and serve

Comment: It would display the error in the `laravel.log`

Comment: the error is not displayed in the file, any other ways can check

Comment: Check your server logs, apache/nginx error logs